# Move chain segment without "breaking" the chain

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my 2D game I have setup a chain with hinge joints programatically. I want to be able to click and drag one of the links and when I release I want it to snap back to its original position. But when I change transform.position on the chain segment, the joint position is also shifted so it stays at that offset.

How would I move a chain segment and the have it snap back so the chain stays intact.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a complex and complicated problem. You're dealing with both Kinematics and Inverse Kinematics here, possibly even some physics. Not a fun problem.

Comment: I started to worry about your answer, and had planed a lot of complex solutions during the weekend. BUT one simple line of code did fix the problem. I had totally overlooked the autoConfigureConnectedAnchor setting. 

`joint.autoConfigureConnectedAnchor = false;` and the segments snaps back as wanted. yey!

Comment: Oh good. I haven't played around with such things, so I'm glad there was a simpler answer